# Are these definitions of Borel $\sigma$-field and Borel sets correct$?$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, definition, borel-sets

I encountered a bit different definition of Borel $\sigma$-field and Borel sets. Possibly the reason is that I'm not accustomed to these definitions w.r.t. topological spaces. In any case, I'd like to verify these definitions $($marked in the red rectangle$)$. Please let me know whether they are correct or not. Thank you.[image]

Comment: How are these different than the definitions you have seen previously?

Comment: Why the doubt/scepticism?

Comment: @JohnGriffin I studied it w.r.t. metric spaces..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are completely correct.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!